# Find output given state space representation

Tags: control-system, state-space

This is usually easy but there are things I haven't encountered in this one. This is the problem. $$\dot x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-2&-3\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}u=Ax+Bu\\y=\begin {bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}x=Cx\\x(0)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

First I'm asked to calculate $$x(t)=e^{At}x(0)$$

An exponential matrix in a control theory course seems a bit too much but I solved that. $$x(t)=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e^{-1t}&0\\0&e^{-2t}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
The second and final question asks me to find the expression of the output y(t) for any input u(t).

Looking at the solution manual this is all that's written : $$y(t)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\int_0^t\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e^{-1(t-τ)}&0\\0&e^{-2(t-τ)}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}u(τ)dτ$$

That reminds me of convolution but the integral limits are different. Plus the result from the first question is used. Why would we use the exponential? I can't make the connection and understand the second part. Any ideas?

Comment: Can Laplace transform be used in the solution?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Sure, but I would mostly like to understand what he did here.

Comment: u(t) is heaviside function or any function?

Comment: Any function, sorry for the confusion @pasabaporaqui. It's not easy writing all those matrixes.

Comment: In Laplace space: sX(s)-x(0)=AX(s)+BU(s) => X(s)=(BU(s)+x(0))/(sI-A); thus, x(0) term produces x(t)=x(0)e^At; what I do not understand is why term for u(t) is ignored when you say "First I'm asked to calculate x(t)=..."

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I still don't get how x(0)e^At comes up. As for that, I'm just asked to calculate x(0)e^At which simply doesn't include u.

Comment: Inverse Laplace of x(0)/(sI-A) is x(0)e^(At), look at any Laplace table

Comment: Now I get it, thanks @pasabaporaqui. Any ideas about the second part ?

Comment: Do you know about modal matrix, spectral matrix, and  matrix exponential (particularly a diagonal matrix)? And the relationship between these?

Comment: A succinct explanation of the transition matrix is given in the Schaum's Outline series on Feedback and Control Systems by DiStefano et all.  It is probably a good book to look at if you're going through problems like these.

Comment: No Chu, our teacher assumes we know many stuff that we actually don't. And the problem is I don't know what that is so I can look for it. Thanks PICy I'll have a look.

Comment: Second term is inverse laplace of product that, as you said, is convolution of the related signals

Comment: I've got some introductory notes on state space that I give to my students. I don't think I can upload here, so I might try to condense them. Unless someone else answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laplace space:

$$ sX(s)-x(0)=AX(s)+BU(s) $$

so:

$$ X(s)=(sI-A)^{-1}BU(s)+(sI-A)^{-1}x(0) $$

the second term, due to the initial condition, produces:

$$ x_0(t)=e^{At}~x(0) $$

while the fist term, due to the incoming signal, produces:

$$ x_u(t)=\int_0^te^{A\tau}~B~u(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)}~~B~u(\tau)~d\tau $$

(where calculation of \$ e^{At} \$ can be seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(%7B%7B0,1%7D,%7B-2,-3%7D%7Dt)) )

Finally:

$$ y(t)=Cx(t)=C(x_u(t)+x_0(t)) $$

Comment: Very helpful. I assume I can also find X(s), replace in Y(s)=CX(s) and then taking the inverse Laplace transform find y(t). Is that correct?

Comment: Taken into account that C is a constant, y(t)=Cx(t) and Y(s)=CX(s), you can do the multiplication in time or Laplace space.

Comment: Is there a chance the initial conditions are not in y(t)? I mean C could cancel them out right?

Comment: No, initial conditions can not be "cancelled" (if you are moving at 100 km/h, you can accelerate or decelerate, but not ignore you are moving). If C is not a constant but c(t) it means that the system is not time invariant. In this case, usually is easier calculation in time space y(t)=c(t)x(t) than calculation in Laplace space  L-1{convolution(L{c(t)},L{x(t)})}

Comment: Fixed some matrix permutations

Comment: I solved a similar problem and the final formula y(t)=C(x(t) +x0(t)) gives Cx0(t)=0 and I'm only left with Cx(t)

Comment: In the case of the original question, the only C that mades zero y0(t) is (0,0)

Comment: Can you have a look ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCw3l.jpg

Comment: I think there are an error in sign of \$ T_{1,2} \$

Comment: You are right but it doesn't affect the result I think. The x(0) still vanishes.

Comment: Man, I want to understand everything the way you do. Any textbooks you can suggest?

Comment: Be careful that in this latest example you are assuming u(t) is the Heaviside function, when you say U(s)=1/s.

Comment: No, do not start by reading books nor taken notes (or going to magisterial class): relax, take time, and thing about what you have in front. Try to visualize and give sense to each part of the problem. Books are for reference, or to stablish an ordenation in the matter.

Comment: (numbering rows and columns 1,2,..): \$ A_{2,1} = 0 \$ thus \$ x_2(t) \$ is unrelated of \$ x_1(t) \$; \$ B_1=0 \$ thus \$ x_2(t) \$ is unrelated to \$ u_1(t) \$, \$ x_2'(t)=2u_2(t) \$; finally, as C=(0,1), output y(t) is only related to \$ x_2(t) \$, \$ y(t)=x_2(t)\$. As result, the system is simply \$ y'(t)=2u(t) \$, an integrator.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do schools teach so many things? They do not leave time to learn anything.

Comment: That is true in many cases unfortunately. There are many times I think they are trying to cover too much stuff in too little time.Anyway,I'll try to do as you said and be able to face the problem this way. Thanks for your time and help pasaba.